# How to add/remove custom Code snippets in Xcode 11 and above

Tags: ios, xcode10

How to drag and drop a custom code to code snippets and use a shortcut text for auto-fill as we did in Xcode < 10

[image]

And how to remove the snippets?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## How to add

---

In Xcode
select line or code  to be added in code snippet and then

**Option1**

1. Goto Editor
2. choose  the Create code snippet

[image]

**Option 2**

Select Code you want to add to snippet
right click and choose create code snippet

## How to Remove

---

Choose any snippet and press **backspace**
[image]

---

## How to Edit

---

If you want to edit already added code snippet it is easy. just open code snippet library list (from right corner) from the list select code snippet you want to edit and press **SPACE BAR** button

[image]

Warning : My Xcode  crashes randomly  couple of time during removing or adding code snippet make sure you save your work (Xcode 10 BUG) :]

Hope it is helpful

Comment: how to remove..?

Comment: TO remove it press backspace on code snippet window after select

Comment: @Saranjith added as answer :)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Working! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13):

### **Update for Xcode 11**

**Add code snippet**

Same way as before:

1. Select code
2. Right click on it
3. Create Code Snippet

---

**Edit and Delete code snippet**

Type `cmd + shift + L` and you will see the following UI:

[image]

---

For more information about Xcode code snippets check [this article](https://medium.com/@mjurfest/helpful-code-snippets-for-ios-21aa5ef894de).

Answer (score 8):

To add new code snippet in `XCODE 10`, you can just:
- select the codes that you want to create snippet
- then right-click on those selected codes
 - choose Create code snippet.

[image]

And to remove the code snippets:
 - Just click on the `{}` icon on the top right nav
 - Then select on the code snippet you want to delete
 - Press `Backspace`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you still want to use `Drag & Drop` way to create a new code snippet as we did until Xcode 9, you can open Library dialog (shortcut: `[Command]` + `[Option]` + `[Shift]` + `[L]`) and drag the source code into the dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## To edit the snippet

- Click on the show panel icon on top right of the Snippet popup
  window.
- Window will expand to show the code and also the Edit button

### Click on panel icon

[image: Expand panel]

### Edit button now visible

[image]